Can't SSH into a device behind a gateway through VPN Tunnel
I am having trouble trying to ssh into a VM that is running on another PC with Proxmox from outside the network through a VPN tunnel.
Here are some details:

I am connecting through a wireless hotspot.
I am running openvpn on a gateway. The VPN subnet is 192.168.8.X
Behind the gateway the endpoint is at 192.168.45.X.
netmask for both is 255.255.255.0.
The VPN has forwarding rule to forward traffic from 192.168.8.x to 192.168.45.x
I can reach other devices behind the gateway and ssh to them just fine.
I can ping the target device.
TCP dump on the target device shows ssh requests are coming through.
ufw is disabled and iptables set to ACCEPT on INPUT,OUTPUT,FORWARD.
The OS is ubuntu-server 22.02

The strange thing is I can SSH from the hotspot into the target, but not from the device connected to the hotspot.

“The VPN has forwarding rule to forward traffic from 192.168.8.0 to 192.168.45.0” - Neither of those addresses are valid, why are you not forwarding the address of the server 192.168.8.X to 192.168.45.X instead?

How can you have subnets 192.168.8.X and 192.168.45.X when the netmask is 255.255.0.0? That effectively make hosts with such netmask consider both IP blocks the same subnet (192.168.X.X, more properly 192.168.0.0/16). Assuming your VM is bridged the LAN (which I assume to be where "192.168.45.X" is used with netmask of 255.255.0.0), it means that even when the VM tries to reply to some 192.168.8.X, it will try to resolve the IP with ARP instead of sending the reply to the gateway/hotspot.

Regarding point 4 – is the netmask actually 255.255.0.0 for both networks?

Actually you are right. I must have mistyped. The actual subnet is 255.255.255.0 on both machines

Sounds like you have firewall rule on the target host that drops SSH requests from source IP outside 192.168.45.0/24. Check iptables-save and nft list ruleset.

I would agree with you on the firewall issue, except that if I connect to the VPN from my phone (which is also the hotspot) I am able to ssh into the targetbox.

@Equinox You mentioned that TCP dump on the target device shows ssh requests are coming through, but do you see the ssh server emitting responses? And anything in its log? Also, where do you tcpdump?

This might be a partial answer, but ultimately I found the issue to be connecting through the hotspot.
After disconnecting my PC from the hotspot and using another gateway, I was able to SSH into the target machine.
Maybe Android/Mobile ISP has some rules about what traffic it will forward?
